# git - Merging a hotfix into dev and master causes divergence

Tags: git, branch

I am following [a success Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (aka git-flow).

I did a hotfix following the guidance in the section *Finishing a hotfix branch*.

I created a *hotfix* branch off *master*:

```
> git checkout -b hotfix upstream/master
```

Did some work and manually merged it into *master*:

```
> git checkout master 
> git merge --no-ff hotfix
```

Then manually merged it back into *dev*:

```
> git checkout dev
> git merge --no-ff hotfix
```

I did some more work - made commits against *dev*. Everything seemed fine. But then when I went to merge *dev* into *master*, it could not.

```
> git checkout master
> git merge --ff-only dev
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

It appears the merge commit from the *hotfix* is the difference.

I assumed following this process would keep a common history. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to merge dev into master with fast-forward?

Comment: @alexeyten, I thought to avoid merge commits... from [the article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) *when develop branch reaches a stable point and is ready to be released, all of the changes should be merged back into master **somehow***

Answer (score 5):

You didn’t provide specifics about the topology of your history, so beginning with a general case and creating `hotfix` gives

```
$ git checkout -b hotfix upstream/master
$ git lola
* 81a514a (dev) Stupendous feature
* cb4d5e6 Great feature
* d4a7906 Cool feature
| * 39e449a (HEAD, upstream/master, hotfix) v0.2
|/
* 264ddbc (master) v0.1
```

Note: [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a nonstandard but highly useful alias.

Merging `hotfix` to `master` gives

```
*   567f066 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
|\
| * 1b1b6e3 (hotfix) Fix nasty bug
| * 39e449a (upstream/master) v0.2
|/
| * 81a514a (dev) Stupendous feature
| * cb4d5e6 Great feature
| * d4a7906 Cool feature
|/
* 264ddbc v0.1
```

Merging `hotfix` separately to `dev` is where things go off track.

```
*   36aa1c8 (HEAD, dev) Merge branch 'hotfix' into dev
|\
* | 81a514a Stupendous feature
* | cb4d5e6 Great feature
* | d4a7906 Cool feature
| | *   567f066 (master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
| | |\
| |/ /
|/| /
| |/
| * 1b1b6e3 (hotfix) Fix nasty bug
| * 39e449a (upstream/master) v0.2
|/
* 264ddbc v0.1
```

At this point, `master` is not a direct ancestor of `dev` but its sibling.

Adding more commits to `dev` makes `master` its great uncle.

```
* d89aa74 (HEAD, dev) Jason does it again
* a4dd5bf Jason saves the day
*   36aa1c8 Merge branch 'hotfix' into dev
|\
* | 81a514a Stupendous feature
* | cb4d5e6 Great feature
* | d4a7906 Cool feature
| | *   567f066 (master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
| | |\
| |/ /
|/| /
| |/
| * 1b1b6e3 (hotfix) Fix nasty bug
| * 39e449a (upstream/master) v0.2
|/
* 264ddbc v0.1
```

Recall that `dev` gets to `master` by way of a feature branch, and through `--no-ff` merges. Perhaps `release-1.0` begins with your hotfix and gets another bug fix.

```
* f0398ba (HEAD, release-1.0) Bugfix for v1.0
* d89aa74 (dev) Jason does it again
* a4dd5bf Jason saves the day
*   36aa1c8 Merge branch 'hotfix' into dev
|\
* | 81a514a Stupendous feature
* | cb4d5e6 Great feature
* | d4a7906 Cool feature
| | *   567f066 (master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
| | |\
| |/ /
|/| /
| |/
| * 1b1b6e3 (hotfix) Fix nasty bug
| * 39e449a (upstream/master) v0.2
|/
* 264ddbc v0.1
```

Assuming that buttons up the release, this goes back to `master` with

```
$ git merge --no-ff -m "v1.0" release-1.0
$ git lola
*   5a384c8 (HEAD, master) v1.0
|\
| * f0398ba (release-1.0) Bugfix for v1.0
| * d89aa74 (dev) Jason does it again
| * a4dd5bf Jason saves the day
| *   36aa1c8 Merge branch 'hotfix' into dev
| |\
| * | 81a514a Stupendous feature
| * | cb4d5e6 Great feature
| * | d4a7906 Cool feature
* | |   567f066 Merge branch 'hotfix'
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| /
| |/
| * 1b1b6e3 (hotfix) Fix nasty bug
| * 39e449a (upstream/master) v0.2
|/
* 264ddbc v0.1
```

Of course, the exact fix for you depends on the specifics of your history.

Comment: What *specifics* do you need? I appreciate the explanation, but its yet to answer my question. Allow me to ask a new one, how should I have done this?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary You may be fairly close. Remember that the merge back to `master` is `--no-ff`, but your question tried to do it with `--ff-only`. Under the fully general model, `dev` merges into `release-*`, which then merges into `master`. See the last two sections of my answer. If that still doesn’t answer your question, consider pasting the relevant output of `git lola` into your answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing my merges from *dev* to *master* wrong. I thought you wanted to avoid merge commits when merging between branches. To keep a clean history in case of such things as a hotfix. Hence the `--ff-only`. Are you saying under git-flow I want merge commits?

Comment: Notice in [the git flow picture](http://nvie.com/img/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png) that every commit in `master` beyond 0.1 has multiple parents, *i.e.*, each is a merge commit. You are correct that a workflow based on `git merge --ff-only` or `git rebase` will generally produce cleaner, linear history—but at the cost of discarding useful historical context, *e.g.*, the exact commits that were reviewed, lifetimes of individual issues, and so on. Some history hygiene with rebasing and squashing is still useful as long as it preserves enough artifacts to tell the whole story.

Comment: So when it is time to merge *dev* into *master*, you do so with a `git merge --no-ff`. This would diverge *master* and *dev*. But I guess you don't care as *dev* would never pull directly from *master*, only through a *hotfix*-type branch. However, I'm still confused, because wouldn't that make it difficult to create a *hotfix* branch since *dev* and *master* are diverged? Over time you'd have to go pretty far back to find the common ancestor.